# $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ V.S. $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Generally we know that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is bigger then $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ for arbitrary $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ and also we have $W_0^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)=W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$. Today I found on H. Brezis book a remark states that for domain $\Omega$, if $\mathbb R^N\setminus \Omega$ is "sufficiently thin" and $p<N$, then $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)= W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

What does he means by **"sufficiently thin"**? And how we prove this remark? I don't have an idea to get start...

Also, it gives an example. By defining $\Omega:=\mathbb R^N\setminus\{0\}$ and $N\geq 2$, one can prove that $H_0^1(\Omega)=H^1(\Omega)$.

I tried to prove this example by using approximation. But I think, since $C_c^\infty(\Omega)\neq C^\infty (\Omega)$, why should we have $H_0^1(\Omega)=H^1(\Omega)$?

Any help is really welcome. Thank you!

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is pretty technical and involves *Sobolev capacity*. See [Theorem 4.8 here](http://users.jyu.fi/~terok/preprints/nolla.pdf). This paper deals with more general metric spaces, but the arguments are adapted after Euclidean spaces; I haven't found an easily available source for the Euclidean case. The proof of Theorem 4.8 will suggest you how to deal with $H_0^1=H^1$: multiply by a suitable smooth cutoff function.

Comment: There is also a characterization in terms of polar set. Take a look in [Adams-Fournier book](http://www.amazon.com/Sobolev-Spaces-Second-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0120441438/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1420475835&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=adams+sobole), chapter 3.

Comment: thanks guys! I'll check the reference you provided.